# `Array#each_slice`, leaving remainders at the beginning

Tags: arrays, ruby, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to slice an array into groups of three. I want to have the remainders at the beginning (`[1, 2]` in the following example).

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
...
#=> [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11]]
```

Is there a nifty way to do this?

The usual way to split an array would be:

```
arr.each_slice(3)
# => [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11]]
```

This gives the remainders `[10, 11]` at the end. I tried as below, thinking `each_slice` might accept a negative argument and read it as going backwards through the array.

```
arr.each_slice(-3)
```

Alas, it didn't work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Though one might reverse an array thrice, there is more efficient way to achieve a goal:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
a = arr.dup # not to modify it inplace
[a.shift(a.size % 3)] + a.each_slice(3).to_a
#⇒ [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11]]
```

BTW, `arr.each_slice(3)` returns an enumerator, not an array as you posted in the question.

**upd** or, as suggested by Cary Swoveland, to void `dup`:

```
n = a.size % 3
[a[0...n]] + a[n..-1].each_slice(3).to_a
```

**upd** getting rid of `dup` by @sawa:

```
[a.first(a.size % 3)] + a.drop(a.size % 3).each_slice(3).to_a
```

**upd** just out of curiosity (assuming an input has no `nil` elements):

```
([nil] * (3 - a.size % 3) + a).each_slice(3).to_a.tap do |a|
  a.unshift(a.shift.compact!)
end
```

the above might be safely run on original array, it does not modify it inplace.

**UPD2** as pointed out by Stefan in comments, any of the above will produce an initial empty slice if the array is divisible by 3. So, the proper solution (and, the fastest, btw) should look like:

```
(arr.size % 3).zero? ? arr.each_slice(3).to_a : ANY_OF_THE_ABOVE
```

Comment: Good answer. To avoid `dup`: `n = a.size(3); a[0,n] + a[n..-1].slice(3)`.

Comment: If you use `first(n)` and `drop(n)`, then you don't have to `dup`.

Comment: All of these will produce an initial empty slice if the array is divisible by 3, e.g. `[[], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]`

Answer (score 7):

A simple combination of `reverse` and `each_slice` will do the trick:

```
arr.reverse.each_slice(3).map(&:reverse).reverse
#=> [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11]]
```

**Explanation:**

I am reversing the Array and doing `each_slice`. That will give me:

```
[[11, 10, 9], [8, 7, 6], [5, 4, 3], [2, 1]]
```

Now I'm iterating over this and reversing each sub-arrays to match the expected sub-array sequence with `.map(&:reverse)`. At last I am reversing the whole Array to get the desired sequence (with last `.reverse`).

Comment: I was about to post `arr.reverse.each_slice(3).map{|a| a.reverse}.reverse`. :-D

Comment: This reads well and should be fast. You could eliminate one array by replacing the first `reverse` with `reverse_each`.

Comment: Thanks for this - all comments have been great. Evidently many ways to skin a cat! 

Just wondering, the map(&:reverse) bit kinda threw me. Is that short form for something?